# How to Save location Coordinates in sqlite or CoreData with significant location monitoring in swift

Tags: swift, core-data, cllocationmanager, fmdb

I would like to save the coordinates in location manager didUpdateLocation delegate function. The application could be in suspended or background state so can't rely on array.I am hoping to save it using FMDB or CoreData but I need to know if i can save recorded location normally or do I need to use background expiration handler. If it's the later please share a reliable way to do so in swift.

I am using significant location monitoring which is working fine.

Comment: What is a "background expiration handler"?

Comment: I meant "beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler". This handler is called shortly before the app’s remaining background time reaches 0. It should be used to clean up and ensure that we had enough time to complete some long process like transfer an important file to a remote server or at least attempt to make the transfer and note any errors.

Comment: I wanted to know if saving data in FMDB will run fine without it and will app have enough time to save data into sqlite if it's waking up from suspend state.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of time. At least I did it in my app without the need to use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`

Nevertheless consider to use `allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled` to reduce energy consumption while in background.

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier and safer to split the function up.  When I get a call to the locationManager didUpdateLocations delegate, I quickly append the location points to an array of pending locations and exit.  Then I use a timer driven processPendingPoints function to periodically add the new points in the pending locations array to my map and clear out the array, where the timer and processing function will only run when the app is in the foreground (which is fine for my purposes).

Generally, I use a 10 second delay for the pending locations processor but slow down this and other processes when the battery is low.  Since I don't need to be quick in this method, I can recenter or resize the map and do other utility things as well as adding the points.